# Memory metric for Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

being new to Azure in general and `Azure ARM templates` precisely, I'm trying to write some template to upload to azure.

I want to set an `autoscale` resource to scale my `VM scale` sets according to Processor and Memory.

The problem is that all I could find on the internet is the metric of Processor time, as mentioned here on as a variable in the Json file :

```
"ProcessorMetricName": "\\Processor\\PercentProcessorTime"
```

My question is what would I add to make an autoscale based on the memory state ? I mean something like :

```
 "MemoryMetricName": "\\???\\???"
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the metrics based on memory state you can set to auto-scale would be:

**`Memory\Available MBytes`** **/* Memory Available */**

E.g.

```
                   "metricTrigger": {
                        "metricName": "\\Memory\\Available MBytes",
                        "timeGrain": "PT5M",
                        "statistic": "Average",
                        "timeWindow": "PT5M",
                        "timeAggregation": "Average",
                        "operator": "GreaterThan",
                        "threshold": 1073741824 /* Number of bytes */
                    }
```

Comment: Okey, thx for the answer, can you please hand a link where I can find all the metric names to be used in template ?

Comment: No I don't have that. They are basically the performance counters names based on the operating system type of your VM.